# What’s the difference between res.send and app.post?

Tags: javascript, express, http, get, send

I’m new to express and HTTP. The express library has app.get, app.post and res.send. As I understand it, app.get uses/is used with GET and app.post POST. Does res.send call POST?

Comment: `res` is normal the short for response, a response doesn't do a POST, the client do.  You can listen for a post with something like `app.post((req, res) => {})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.send()` sends a response to an incoming http request that has come into your http server.

`app.post()` registers a request handler with Express for a specific URL in your http server and for POST requests so that when your Express server receives a POST request at that URL, it will call this request handler.

Here's an example of `res.send()`:

```
// configure request handler for GET request to /
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hi");               // send response to incoming http request
});
```

Here's an example of `app.post()`:

```
// this middleware reads and parses the body for content-type
// of  application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// configure request handler for POST request to /login
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
     // in a real request handler, this would be some sort of username
     // and password comparison in a database and using appropriate crypto
     if (req.body.username === "John" && req.body.password === "foobar99") {
         res.send("login successful");
     } else {
         res.status(401).send("Login failed");
     }
});
```

> The express library has res.get and res.send.  As I understand it, res.get uses / is used with GET.

You are perhaps confused because there is no `res.get`.  Perhaps you meant `app.get()`?  If so, `app.get()` configures a request handler for an http GET request to a specific URL.  So, `app.get("/books", ...)` might display a page of all available books.

> Does res.send call POST?

No.  `res.send()` sends a response to an http request.

Here are the steps you can think of.

1. An http client (such as a browser or any piece of code) creates an http request and sends that request to a server.
2. That request will have both an HTTP verb such as GET, POST, PATCH, etc... and it will have a URL such as `/login` or `/books`.
3. The web server that the request was sent to receives that request.  In the case of a web server using the Express framework, the Express server looks through its list of already registered routes (these routes were previously registered with `app.get(...)`, `app.post(...)`, `app.use(...)`, etc...  These are essentially listeners for specific routes.  If the Express server finds an already registered route that matches both the http request verb and the URL, then it calls that route handler and pass it three arguments `(req, res, next)`.
4. When the request handler code gets called, it can examine the `req` object to see any data about the incoming request such as the exact URL, any http headers on the request and so on.  It can use the `res` object for sending a response such as setting any http headers on the response, setting content-type, setting an http status code for the response, creating and sending the body of the response, etc...   `res.send()` is one way to send the response.  There are also others such as `res.sendFile()`, `res.json()`, `res.sendStatus()` and so on...
5. After one of these methods is called that sends the response, then the underlying engine sends that http response back to the client that sent the original http request and the HTTP request/response is considered complete.

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different modules/objects..

The [Express Router](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) supports HTTP methods for the server to listens and respond to - `.get()`, `.post()`, `.put()`.

One of the arguments passed through the chain of middleware and handlers is the [Response](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res), which has a `.send()` method to send its response back to the client. The Response object can also be enhanced to send JSON, etc.